# How to eliminate null arguments without having redundant codes

Tags: java, parameters, null

For example:

```
getBooks(author, title)
```

- If allowing author to be null, would return all books with specific title
- If allowing title to be null, would return all books for the specific author
- If allowing both to be null, would return all books regardless of title or author

To eliminate this, have the following functions:

```
getBooks(author) 
getBooks(title)  
getBooks(author, title)  
getBooks()
```

In the new functions, there might be redundant codes or if we group those redundant codes into a function, we will still get into a function having null parameters. What's a better way to handle this - no redundant code and no null parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't overload so much:

```
getBooksByAuthor(author) 
getBooksByTitle(title)  
getBooksByAuthorAndTitle(author, title)  
getBooks()
```

Note that this will not reduce code reuse: These methods could reuse/share whatever code they needed to in their implementations

Comment: Completely agree. These kind of things become a lot more apparent when you actually start using your code (via TDD). Making calls such as `getBooks(null, false, 'author', null)` is a maintenance nightmare (even in your tests).

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
getAllBooks()            {return getBooks("", "");}
getBooksByAuthor(author) {return getBooks(author, "");}
getBooksByTitle(title)   {return getBooks("", title);}
getBooksByAuthorAndTitle(author, title)
{
    if(author.equals("") && title.equals(""))
    {
        return //your book list
    }
    else if(author.equals(""))
    {
        return //a list of books with the given title
    }
    else if(title.equals(""))
    {
        return //a list of books with given author
    }
    else
    {
        return //a list of books with the given title and author
    }
}
```

*Edit*:
Updated to circumvent ambiguity.

Comment: I see a big problem: `getBooks(author)` and `getBooks(title)` both have the same method signature: `getBooks(String str)`, and so the there's no way that the compiler or your logic will know which one is desired. So this won't work.

Comment: title/author could be objects. Otherwise, you're right that is a problem.

Comment: Perhaps, but in your code, there's no ambiguity: they're both Strings, and this simply won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a constant to denote what type of search to do, and check to see if a param was passed (very untested and error checked):

```
public static final int R_AUTH = 1;
public static final int R_BOOK = 2;
public static final int R_ALL = 3;

public bookSearch( int searchType, String... search )
{
    switch( searchType )
    {
        case R_AUTH:
          // search based off of (String)search[0].stringValue();
        break;
        case R_ALL:
          // load all
        break;
    }
}

bookSearch(R_ALL);
bookSearch(R_AUTH, "Poe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that author and title are Strings you can do the following:

```
public List getBooks(String params ...) {
    if (params.length == 0) { //search 
     //do search all books regardless of title or author
    } else if (params.length == 2 && "cte_author".equals(params[1])) {
     //do search  by author
    } else if (params.length == 2 && "cte_title".equals(params[1])) {
     //do search by title
    } else if (params.length == 2){
     //do search by title and book
    } else {
     //throw exception
    }
}
```

So you can use this method as following:

```
getBooks();
getBooks("Gabriel Garcia Marquez", "cte_author");
getBooks("Cien anios de soledad", "cte_title");
getBooks("Gabriel Garcia Marquez","Cien anios de soledad");
```

Comment: In any case I preffer the solution provided by @Bohemian